# Command to center screen horizontally around cursor on emacs?

Tags: emacs, editor, navigation, elisp

I'm familiar with and use very frequently the `C-l` (`recenter-top-bottom`) to

> Move current line to window center,
>   top, and bottom, successively.

I'd like to have an equivalent command to move the current *column* to window center, left and right borders, successively. Either built-in or a snippet of Elisp.

Comment: `C-h f recenter` (my version (GNU 22.3) doesn't have recenter-top-bottom, what version are you using?) says this function is implemented in the c-core of emacs, so it may not be trivial to get the horizontal behavior in elisp. Consider patching the source?

Comment: I'm running GNU 23.0.91.1 from the ubuntu emacs-snapshot package version 1:20090320-1ubuntu1. The only difference between `recenter` and `recenter-top-bottom` is that, in the latter, repeating the command cycles between putting the cursor at the center, at the top and at the bottom.

Horizontal scrolling already exists with `C-x C-<` and `C-x C->` and with normal `C-f` when you get close to the right border, so I don't think we'd have to go all the way to the emacs core.

Comment: @obvio171 `C-x C-<` and `C-x C->` are undefined in my (almost bare) config. Can you specify where you did get them from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(defun my-horizontal-recenter ()
  "make the point horizontally centered in the window"
  (interactive)
  (let ((mid (/ (window-width) 2))
        (line-len (save-excursion (end-of-line) (current-column)))
        (cur (current-column)))
    (if (< mid cur)
        (set-window-hscroll (selected-window)
                            (- cur mid)))))
```

And the obvious binding (from [obvio171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105132/obvio171)) is:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-l") 'my-horizontal-recenter)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Bound it to C-S-l, works like a charm! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Nice ! I've added this function to integrate yours in `C-l` binding, only if you are in truncate-lines mode :

    (defun my-recenter ()
      "center vertically and horizontally in truncate-lines mode"
      (interactive)
      (if (equal truncate-lines t)
          (my-horizontal-recenter))
      (recenter-top-bottom))
    (global-set-key "\C-l" 'my-recenter)

Comment: This only does the re-centering.  However, successive presses of `C-l` cycle center, top, bottom successively.  Would be nice if this answer could be expanded to include the complete cycle.

Comment: This is beautiful. Should be part of Emacs. I would suggest the name `recenter-left-right`. Also I agree with @ChristianHerenz.

Comment: Nice. No need for extra binding, here's what I have:

```(defadvice recenter-top-bottom (after my-horizontal-recenter activate)
  "when re-centering window vertically around cursor, also do it horizontally"
  (interactive)
  (my-horizontal-recenter))

```

Answer (score 4):

If you move to a chosen column and hit C-x C-n, then the commands C-n and C-p will go to that column until you hit C-u C-x C-n to turn the behavior off.

A sort of poor-man's version of what you are looking for.

Comment: This only limits the column which the cursor can be at, but doesn't move the text horizontally. What I want is for the column the cursor is at to be "dragged" to the center of the screen, doing a horizontal scroll.